# How do I position my two buttons to the center?

Tags: html, css

> My problem is how do I position my two buttons to the center? Also, how do I take off the gray color inside the two buttons?
>
> Here is the code:
>
> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>
                PRODIGIES
                <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/>
            </h1>
        </header>

        
        <div class = "topic-text">
            <h3>
                Learn Elementary Math.
            </h3>

            <h3>
                Fun and Easy!
            </h3>
            
        </div>

        <div class = "page-text">
            <p>
                Learn and master Math from Grade 1 to Grade 5.
            </p>

            <p>
                We will show you all the tips and tricks to solve Math Problems faster!
            </p>
    
        </div>

        <button class = "button1">I am a Parent</button>
        <button class = "button2">I am a Student</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

> documentation.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header class = "header_doc">
            <h1>
                DOCUMENTATION
            </h1>
        </header>
    </body>

</html>
```

> teachings.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "rest.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                WHAT WILL I TEACH?
                <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

> signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                SIGN UP
                <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

> style.css

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(48, 176, 235); /*The background color of the page*/
    color: rgb(199, 195, 195); /*The color of the words*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; /*The font family of the website*/
}

header{
    font-size: 30px; /*The font size of the header*/
    text-align: center; /* The alignment of the title, Prodigies*/
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /*The background color of the header*/
}

footer {
    text-align: left;
  }
  
footer h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: silver;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;

}

ul li ul li {
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(15, 98, 253, 0.2);
}

.topic-text{
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 86px;
    height: 190px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(48, 176, 235); 
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(30, 109, 255);
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(238, 237, 237);
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.7s; 
  }

.page-text{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
  }

.button1{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border: 19px solid white;
}

.button2{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 80px;
    border: 19px solid white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

> To re-explain I don't know how to position my two buttons to the center. I also don't know how to take out the gray color inside my two buttons. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use flexbox and apply background-color

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
margin-top:150px;
}
.button{
margin:5px;
background-color:green;
width:10vw;
height:10vh;}

a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>
                PRODIGIES
                <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/>
            </h1>
        </header>

        
        <div class = "topic-text">
            <h3>
                Learn Elementary Math.
            </h3>

            <h3>
                Fun and Easy!
            </h3>
            
        </div>

        <div class = "page-text">
            <p>
                Learn and master Math from Grade 1 to Grade 5.
            </p>

            <p>
                We will show you all the tips and tricks to solve Math Problems faster!
            </p>
    
        </div>
        <div id='container'>
        <button class = "button">I am a Parent</button>
        <button class = "button">I am a Student</button>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id='container2'> <a href = "documentation.html"> <button class = "button" href = "documentation.html">I AM A PARENT</button> <button class = "button">I AM A STUDENT</button> </a> </div>
        
        
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I lower the height of both buttons?

Comment: add top margin to the container. snippet updated. if this works for you please accept answer

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! You helped a lot!

Comment: One last question, how would I make the buttons larger?

Comment: just add width and height.  use vw and vh units to make the button size responsive to the screen size

Comment: I tried to make the two buttons lead to another page. It works but a small line shows up between both buttons. How can I fix this?

Comment: do you mean underneath or in between? you'll need to show code that's causing the problem.  If it's just the link try text-decoration:none

Comment: Here: index.html

Comment: <div id='container'>
        <a href = "documentation.html">
        <button class = "button" href = "documentation.html">I AM A PARENT</button>
        <button class = "button">I AM A STUDENT</button>
        </a>
    </div>

Comment: I'm trying to get the button to lead to another file. It does work but a small line gets made between the two buttons. Run it in the code Snippet

Comment: on the css add -->  a{text-decoration:none;}